# Filtering array of objects with predicate by function

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm pretty new to NSPredicate, and sorry if this is newbie question, but I'v done my research and couldn't find answer to this.

I would like to filter array of custom objects by their function, not property.

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%@ LIKE %@", [times objectAtIndex:x] ,[unit realTime]];
NSArray *filtered  = [objectArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

the `objectArray` contains only `unit` Objects. And i would like to filter the array by each object in Array by `[unit realTime]` method result. Basically I'd like to have filtered array where `[times objectAtIndex:x] == [unit realTime]`. Is this possible to do?

Comment: Check if this works, `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K LIKE %@", unit.realTime, [times objectAtIndex:x]];`

Comment: Sorry, nop. unit.realTime gets as undeclared identifier.

Comment: Why dont you declare `realTime` as an `@property`(readonly) in `unit` and then implement `realTime` method. Is that possible?

Comment: Hmm, sorry but I couldn't grasp the idea. realTime method is already implement in unit Class. Could you be more specific or give a simple example ?

Comment: You can add `realTime` as an `@property() NSDate *realTime;` in Unit.h file and then implement `realTime` method just like how you have already done. That way `realTime` is a param in class and you are overriding the getter method with your custom implementation. It shouldnt show an `undeclared identifier` error in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `realTime` as an `@property() NSDate *realTime;` in Unit.h file and then implement `realTime` method just like how you have already done. That way `realTime` is a param in class and you are overriding the getter method with your custom implementation. It shouldnt show an `undeclared identifier` error in this case.

Once you have done that, change the predicate statement as,

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K LIKE %@", unit.realTime, [times objectAtIndex:x]];
NSArray *filtered  = [objectArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

You should use `%K` to for `unit.realTime` and not `%@`.